# Creating site column with a specific GUID

Tags: 2010, site-column, guid, console-application

I am trying to create a site column using via a console app. I would ultimately like to be able to migrate the site column and upgrade the same column via this app. To that end, I would need some control over the column's GUID. Is it possible to set GUID using the object model for a site column. I could not get a clue from the API: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield_members.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can specify it. Example:

```
public static readonly Guid MyFieldId = 
  new Guid("{CC1E421C-29BE-4373-81D0-55D5D64B2E3D}");
public static readonly string MyFieldDefXml =
  "<Field ID=\"{CC1E421C-29BE-4373-81D0-55D5D64B2E3D}\"" +
  " Name=\"MyFieldName\" StaticName=\"MyFieldName\"" +
  " Type=\"Text\" DisplayName=\"My Field Name\"" +
  " Group=\"My Columns\" DisplaceOnUpgrade=\"TRUE\" />";

if (web.AvailableFields.Contains(MyFieldId) == false)
{
  web.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(MyFieldDefXml);
}
```

More information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798370.aspx#Y209

Comment: Main point here is that you can only do it via XML - so either declaratively in a Feature, or as show here, using the AddFieldAsXml method.

Comment: That's right, James

Comment: Ashish, Thank you. I will try this out. But should the Field "ID" take the value of "MyFieldId" in the code above?

Comment: It takes only a valid GUID

Comment: @Ashish I meant to say: should CC1E421C-29BE-4373-81D0-55D5D64B2E3D be replace by 891B57CF-B826-4B0C-9EDF-8948C824D96F in the above code? I see that ID of MyFieldDefXml is not really being checked. Or may be I am missing something?

Comment: You are right.. both ID should be same.. I will edit that..