# Is it possible to recover a deleted column from a list in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, column, backup, disaster-recovery

I accidentally deleted a column from a list that contained a lot of entered data.

I have no backup of this data, is there any way to recover?

Answer (score 1):

**No**.

Deleted columns or the data of that particular do not go to the Recycle bins.

So, if you don't have its backup, then data is lost.

**Note**: You can create a support ticket with Microsoft and see if they can provide any help regarding data recovery: [Contact support for business products - Admin Help](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/contact-support-for-business-products).

**Similar questions**:

1. [Recover deleted column from SharePoint 2013 list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536541/recover-deleted-column-from-sharepoint-2013-list).
2. [Restore a list column](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/2badf02d-2984-43e0-89d4-26951463eb15/restore-a-list-column).
3. [Restore a deleted field (site column)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158689/restore-a-deleted-field-site-column)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have backup, the data will be lost.

However, you can recreate the same SharePoint column if it is used in some other code:
[Creating site column with a specific GUID](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15648/creating-site-column-with-a-specific-guid)

```
public static readonly Guid MyFieldId = 
  new Guid("{CC1E421C-29BE-4373-81D0-55D5D64B2E3D}");
public static readonly string MyFieldDefXml =
  "<Field ID=\"{CC1E421C-29BE-4373-81D0-55D5D64B2E3D}\"" +
  " Name=\"MyFieldName\" StaticName=\"MyFieldName\"" +
  " Type=\"Text\" DisplayName=\"My Field Name\"" +
  " Group=\"My Columns\" DisplaceOnUpgrade=\"TRUE\" />";

if (web.AvailableFields.Contains(MyFieldId) == false)
{
  web.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(MyFieldDefXml);
}
```